# C++ if statement not parsing whitespace

Tags: c++, if-statement, whitespace, space

My if statement in a c++ console application is not working:

```
string line;
cin >> line;

if (line == "a b"){
    cout << "lalala";
}
```

When I type "a b" nothing happens.
if i use `if (line == "ab")` and type ab it works.

Comment: Hopefully, your teacher explained to you how to use a debugger. If not, you might want to consider finding a better teacher. If you are considering a career in software development, learning how to debug a program with a debugger is a required skill.

Comment: Was the contents of line `a b` or wasn't it?

Comment: `if` is actually working as expected. Your variable `line` didn't contain `"a b"` as you thought.

Comment: To read the whole line use `getline(cin, line);`

Comment: To see the value of `line`, add this before the `if` statement: `std::cout << "line = \"" << line << "\"\n";`

Comment: My debugger disappeared in Dev C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::cin` reads delimited by white-space. So when you read `cin >> line` you are only reading "a" from "a b". Use `std::getline(std::cin, line)` to read the entire line, including white-space (not '\n').

BTW, you could have easily found this problem by looking at your variables with a debugger, or by printing it. Debug your code before posting questions.

NOTE: By `std::cin` I mean the `operator>>`, which has many overloads, as non-members and istream members. The overload that takes a `std::string` reads delimited by white-space.

Comment: It is only the specific `>> a_string` which reads a space delimited string.  You can read whole lines or other forms of input by using different read functions on `std::cin`.

Comment: @M.M Yes, an oversight for simplicity's sake on my part, thanks. I believe the actual overloaded signature is `istream& operator>> (istream& is, char* s)`http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/

Answer (score 3):

Because the reading will end till the whitespace, that means `line` will be `"a"` here.

See [operator>>(std::basic_string)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)

> until one of the following conditions becomes true:
>
> std::isspace(c,is.getloc()) is true for the next character c in is (this whitespace character remains in the input stream).